# I can't understand why we need import Android sdk into project

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I have a strange question,When we develop a android application or others,we need import android.jar into our project,I know if we don't import that jar into project,we can't compile the project and can't generate the apk file,but my question is that our mobile is established on Android system,and Android system contains all classes that in android.jar,when we run our apk file on Android system,which classes it will use.I mean that a Activity class both exist in Android System Framework and Android.jar,which Activity class will be used when application is running.Please someones help me solve this question.Thanks a lot

Comment: Android runs on Delvik which reads .dex file; you write your app in java which is .java file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java is a compiled language.

this is a two step process-- first the code must be *compiled* into byte code, and then the compiled byte code has to actually be run (commonly known as *execution*)

You have probably noticed the difference between compilation errors and runtime errors.  For example, compilation errors are usually seen as a red underline and a red x in eclipse.  Runtime errors occur while the app is running on your phone.

Know what I'm talking about?

So there is a complete separation between the compilation environment (Eclipse) and the runtime environment (Android).  As such, both of them need to know the Android classes and the android sdk must be imported.

Comment: This is a detailed answer.

Comment: So if I add a method in one of classes in android.jar,but that method doesn't exist in android framework(runtime),will it throw a exception,despite I can pass the process of compilation.

Comment: yes.  You can compile with a newer version of android and run on an older version of android (or Java) and get runtime exceptions for `ClassNotFound` or `MethodNotFound`

Comment: @edthethird +1, but Android isn't complied language, its a framework.